# Multiple function inputs from single object in R?

Tags: r

I would like to use a single object to pass multiple inputs to a function in R, is this possible? MWE:

```
df <- data.frame(yes = c(10,20), no = c(50,60),maybe = c(100,200))

fxn <- function(x,y,z){
  a = x + y
  b = x + z
  c = y + z
  return(list(a=a,b=b,c=c))
}

foo <- c("rincon","malibu","steamer")
bar <- c("no","maybe")

df[foo] <- fxn(df$yes,df[bar])
```

In the actual problem, my function has more inputs that are in the default set to `NULL`. I am working in a dynamic shiny context, so the value and length of `bar` is changing. Any help for this newbie would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can create a list of arguments to pass to a function using `alist()`. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With base R you can build the call using `do.call` and create a `list()` of parameters you want to pass to the function

```
do.call("fxn", c(list(df$yes), unname(df[bar])))
```

This would be the same as

```
fxn(df$yes, df[bar][[1]], df[bar][[2]])
```

We need to use the `unname()` because otherwise your parameters would be named "no" and "maybe" while your function is expecting "y" and "z".

The the `rlang` package, you could do

```
library(rlang)
eval_tidy(quo(fxn(df$yes, !!!unname(df[bar]))))
```

That uses the `!!!` splicing operator like some other languages have. Base R does not have such a syntax.